# iFrame Pass username and password inside URL using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have tried the below code to load the iframe page to my view file but was unable to get a response.

```
<section class="slice color-three pb-4">
   <div class="w-section inverse p-0">
     <div class="card col-md-12 pb-4">
        <iframe id="sms_service" src="https://username:password@abc.com/send_sms?account=123456789" height="450" width="100%"></iframe>                                                     
     </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

If I Run a direct URL in the browser then get the iframe page.

So i can pass username, password with that iframe URL.

Answer (score 1):

The way you using the code for load the iframe using htpasswd - basic authentication is seems to correct it may be the issue with Cross-origin.

you can check the Console and see if you getting the Erro for Cross-origin, then you will need to allow the your sit url(where you add this iframe) to source ifram url project or add the allow Cross-origin for your domain to that ifram url script e.g."abc.com/send_sms".